# pasting dd/mm/yyyy dates in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In a text file I have date column as dd/mm/yyyy but when I am pasting the same as it is (paste as values) to google sheets, google sheets converts that to mm/dd/yyyy. That means, 07/06/2017 becomes 06 July and 22/12/2017 becomes invalid dates. I am having to manually change that.

What is the way to force google sheets to stop auto converting dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy ?

Thanks
Kunal

Answer (score 3):

In some regions the default date format is:
`dd/mm/yyyy`, eg Russia. Try changing:

1. File → Spreadsheet Settings...
2. Change locale

Comment: Thanks. It seems working. I changed the locale to India and now it is taking dates in dd/mm/yyyy format. However small glitch. From that point onward, all new sheets are named in "Hindi" language.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your **US** format date is in cell **A2**, this formula will fix it to **European (UK)** date format:

```
=datevalue(text(left(right(A2;len(A2)-find("/";A2));find("/";right(A2;len(A2)-find("/";A2)))-1)&"/"&left(A2;find("/";A2)-1)&"/"&right(right(A2;len(A2)-find("/";A2));len(right(A2;len(A2)-find("/";A2)))-find("/";right(A2;len(A2)-find("/";A2))));"dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

The above formula works even if some dates or months have a trailing zero and others do not, and will add a trailing zero in the final result if needed, that's why it's so long :)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the cell. 
Choose the cell(or cells). There is a format box and "more formats" button.
More Formats -> more formats -> more date and time formats...
from that, you can choose or create a pattern for your project.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help. Because it paste the values automatically. I think the solution should be some where in locale settings. I am exploring.